# How to create a super fine wireframe with low poly?

Tags: texturing, wireframe

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A2oPC4ytFrE

As you can see on the Ironman nanomachine suit, during the transformation, there is a very fine wireframe being formed before the shell forms around it. Currently, I don't have a way to increase the amount of wires without also increasing the resolution of the mesh, so I'm asking, is there a way to create a super fine wireframe using textures, or a way to create more edges without increasing the polycount, sort of like hair children.

Comment: Do you mean this part? - https://ibb.co/x5T99wL

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this - material only, no geometry.

[image: MetalNanoShader]

All it is really, is a mix of two separate Wave Textures (on different axes), clamped by ColorRamps to make sharper "ridges". I softened the effects of the procedural textures (noise and wave) in a few places using MixRGB nodes, mixed with white, and I ran the (multiplied) result of the 2 Wave textures through a Bump Node and into the Normal input of the Principled BSDF.

I slightly warped the input vector using a Noise Texture so the result isn't so "gridlike", and I mixed a bit of Ambient Occlusion shadow effect to make the ridges "pop" even more.